# using declaration for concrete output operator (with concrete signature)

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
namespace nm
{
  class C1 {};
  class C2 {};
  inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs, std::vector<C1> const&) { return lhs; }
  inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs, std::vector<C2> const&) { return lhs; }
}

using nm::operator<<;
```

Is there way to declare to use only one of `operators <<` from namespace `nm` in the global one, and not both?

Comment: What is the use of the `using` declaration?

Comment: `using ns_name::name` using-declaration makes the symbol name from the namespace ns_name accessible for unqualified lookup as if declared in the same class scope, block scope, or namespace as where this using-declaration appears

Comment: Why would you  want to do that. What's your goal

Comment: To use only one operator in the global namespace (or some third namespace). I have changed an example. The operands now are std::vector<C1> and std::vector<C2>. Now AVL is impossible

Comment: If that's your goal, I wonder who would pay for that or who would give you credit points for that (possibly only of use for language lawyers?). Therefore I think our notions of "goal" are different here. With "goal", usually what is meant in these contexts is the thing that necessiated this "using" declaration. For example "if the other operator is also visible, I get an ambiguity with this operator call in this place" (with the corresponding code posted as a minimal testcase) or something similar.

Comment: Suppose, it is necessary only one operator from namespace nm would be available. Suppose, there are many operators << in namespace nm, for example it uses operators << to output information for std::pair objects or std::chrono, and I want to use only that operator I need. Suppose namespace nm have several operators<< for classes not declared in namespace nm itself, like std::vector, or std::pair. In other case, if it is classes declared in nm I don't need using declaration, as AVL lookup will determine the best operator automatically.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to put each `operator<<` in its own nested name space:

```
namespace nm
{
  class C1 {};
  class C2 {};
  namespace nm1 {
    inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs, C1 const&) { return lhs; }
  }
  namespace nm2 {
    inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& lhs, C2 const&) { return lhs; }
  }
}

using nm::nm1::operator<<;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c26389689f3e88a)

Comment: One of them could be `inline`.

Comment: If you have control over the code, you can aswell put the using declaration in between two `namespace nm { ... }` blocks, and declare the other `operator<<` in the second block.

Comment: @РоманКоптев I don't think is possible to treat something like this if you don't have hands on code (at least I'm not aware of something), other than calling explicitly specific overload  of `operator<<` in your code (i.e., `nm::operator<<(std::cout, c1);`)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb Can be written operator in global namespace, that just forwards arguments to operator in namespace nm.